# 3D SLAM & Velodyne HDL-32E

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, 3d-slam, 3dslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know if there's a good 3D SLAM package out there? We have a Velodyne HDL-32E. Thanks to @joq and others, the ROS driver works like a charm. But we haven't found a 3D SLAM package to use it for. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64864/3d-slam-&-velodyne-hdl-32e/) by [xylo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1185/xylo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 184 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chukcha2](https://answers.ros.org/users/25963/chukcha2/) on 2016-03-03**:
@xylo, could you share the results of your search for a 3D SLAM solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that the `ethz_icp_mapper` stack has a pipeline that works with the Velodyne.

You can find more information on the nodes here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ethzasl_icp_mapper

If you look a bit deeper into the packages, there are some preconfigured launch files for Velodyne, I think that it would be a good place to start: https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_icp_mapping/tree/master/ethzasl_icp_mapper/launch/artor

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xylo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1185/xylo/) on 2013-06-13**:
Thanks for the pointer. Unfortunately it doesn't do loop closure, which is essential for reducing the estimate error.

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2015-07-01**:
ethzasl_icp_mapper needs an odometry source right? http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_icp_mapper says that sensor frame → /odom is a required tf Transform.

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2016-04-28**:
can I install ethz_icp_mapper in indigo?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-04-29**:
I don't see any Indigo release of that package. You can try building it from source.